# autoexclusive tool buttons in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qtoolbutton

Here I come up with my another question and this time regarding Qt Tool Buttons AutoExclusive property. Please find my question below:

Q) I have 4 tool buttons which are autoExclusive to each other but the problem I am facing is when I want deselect the selected button its not allowing me to do so(this is the defined behavior in Qt) but I want each button to mutually exclusive to each other as well as be possible to deselect it on clicking the selected button. Can anyone help me with this scenario. Programmatic examples are much more helpful.

Thanks in Advance
Keshav

Comment: [QButtonGroup](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbuttongroup.html) is not enough for your needs ?

Comment: Hi @eyllanesc ... in QButtonGroup if you set autoExclusive , there will be one button always checked what I need is the buttons should behave autoExclusive as well as should be unchecked on click of the checked button.

Comment: @keshavsingh I did not ask you the question, I only edited your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar requirement and ended up in developing a small container for QActions which had roughly the following interface:

```
class ExclusiveActionGroup : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit ExclusiveActionGroup(QObject *parent = 0);
    QAction * addAction ( QAction * action );
    const QAction * checkedAction() const;
    void untrigger();

protected slots:
    void slotActionToggled(bool);

private:
    QList<QAction*> actions;
};
```

The `slotActionToggled` is hooked to the toggle function of the added actions and handles both the exclusivity of the group as well as the deselection (untriggering) of the whole group.
Note that `slotActionToggled` might be triggered within the process of deselecting the corresponding QAction, so your code should handle this (and not toggle the Action again which triggers untoggling which ...)

**ADD-ON** Complete implementation:

```
#include "exclusiveactiongroup.h"
#include <QAction>

#if defined(_MSC_VER) && defined(_DEBUG)
#define DEBUG_NEW new( _NORMAL_BLOCK, __FILE__, __LINE__ )
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif // _MSC_VER

ExclusiveActionGroup::ExclusiveActionGroup(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
}

QAction * ExclusiveActionGroup::addAction ( QAction * action )
{
    actions.push_back(action);
    connect(action, SIGNAL(toggled(bool)), this, SLOT(slotActionToggled(bool)));
    return action;
}

void ExclusiveActionGroup::slotActionToggled ( bool checked )
{
    QAction* action = qobject_cast<QAction*>(sender());
    if (action && checked)
    {
        foreach(QAction* uncheck, actions)
        {
            if (uncheck != action)
            {
                uncheck->setChecked(false); // triggers recursion, doesnt matter though
            }
        }
    }
}

const QAction* ExclusiveActionGroup::checkedAction() const
{
    foreach(const QAction* a, actions)
    {
        if (a->isChecked())
        {
            return a;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void ExclusiveActionGroup::untrigger()
{
    foreach(QAction* a, actions)
    {
        if (a->isChecked())
        {
            a->trigger();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the response, can you if possible send me the example implementation. As I am new to this Qt widget implementation.

Comment: Thanks @Jens. Will test it in my implementation and update you. :)